# Why overwrite the ajax my content div width, if you click an internal links?

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, overwrite

I have a function which load the internal links. The function is work fine except one thing. When you click a link, the content width is changed, to be smaller. I don't know why.

```js
{
$(function() {
 $(".home li.home").removeClass("home").addClass("current_page_item");
 $("#column-warp").append("<img src='/images/ajax-loader.gif' id='ajax-loader'>");

  var $mainContent = $("#content"),
  URL ='',
  siteURL = "http://" + top.location.host.toString(),
  $internalLinks = $('a[href^="' + siteURL + '"]'),
  hash = window.location.hash,
  $ajaxSpinner = $("#ajax-loader"),
  $el, $allLinks = $("a");

  if (hash){
  $ajaxSpinner.fadeIn();
  $mainContent.animate({ opacity: "0.1" });
  $(".current_page_item").removeClass("current_page_item");
  $('a[href="' + hash + '"]').addClass("current_link").parent().addClass("current_page_item");
  hash = hash.substring(1);
  URL = hash + ".entry-content";
  $mainContent.load(URL, function(){
  $ajaxSpinner.fadeOut();
  $mainContent.animate({ opacity: "1" });
  });
 }

  $internalLinks.each(function () {
  $(this).attr("href", "#" + this.pathname);
  }).click(function() {
  $ajaxSpinner.fadeIn();
  $mainContent.animate({ opacity: "0.1" });
  $el = $(this);
  $(".current_page_item").removeClass("current_page_item");
  $allLinks.removeClass("current_link");
  URL = $el.attr("href").substring(1);
  URL = URL + " #content";
  $mainContent.load(URL,function(){
  $el.addClass("current_link").parent().addClass("current_page_item");
  $ajaxSpinner.fadeOut();
  $mainContent.animate({ opacity: "1" });
  });
  });



    });
 })(jQuery);
```

[You can test it this in here](http://neocsatblog.mblx.hu/test/)

Comment: What's wrong on my question?
Anyone tell me,please?
The question is very specifick.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the votedown,i can't ask anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of replacing `#content`, you are returning a new one from your ajax call. Thus, you are nesting `#content` elements.

Either change PHP side (by removing `<div id="comment">` from the result), or Javascript side, by replacing `#content` instead of changing its content.

Comment: Hmm,I'm very new bie in programing, can you show me how to do this in ajax?

Comment: For example, you can change `$mainContent` definition to `$('#container')`

Comment: Everywhere where i see this "$mainContent" change to "$('#container')"?
I good understand you?

Comment: I get some help, and you anwer is correct work with help,thanks!